# Completely disable spell checker

Tags: google-docs, mobile, spell-check

I realize that, in the browser version of Google Documents, you can disable (or at least hide) the spell checker in the **View** options. However, the mobile application has no **View** option.

Where can I find this option there?

It is pretty annoying to have the red underlines all around the place. The option seems not to exist at all. It's not in the document's options nor in the app's main settings. It's the Android app, if that makes any difference.